# Add gesture in my current view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hello i am new in iphone development,

I have some doubt about this , i know i am near to ans but i dont know where i am wrong anyone can please tell where i am wrong .

Here is my code for swipe gesture to my view.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)] autorelease];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

what next in this ...
```

I'm new to iPhone?

Comment: please, format your question with the appropriate flags (i.e. code must be flagged as CODE, in order to improve readability).

Comment: @valvoline, you can suggest your edit to this question too. Then people with enough permissions will approve/reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR; 
gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)] autorelease]; 
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; 
[viewOne addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
```

yup One more line

[gestureR release];